# Highstock start date issue in rangeSelector datepicker when manually changing to out of date range

Tags: highcharts

I have a multiple series chart created in Highstock and each line data starts at different date.

1. Fund A start date : Oct 8, 2002
2. Fund B start date : Nov 15, 1995

On first load the chart will have a start date from Nov 15, 1995 to latest data date.

If I manually key-in the start date at the datepicker for an out of range date e.g. Nov 15, 1990 the datepicker will automatically reset to Fund A start date, Oct 8, 2002.

Any ideas on how to make it to refresh correctly as per initial load date? I would like to avoid the user to have to click the All button again in the rangeSelector.

Link for reference
https://jsfiddle.net/mrseia/j8d2Lrve/4/

```
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions3 = [];
    seriesCounter3 = 0;
    var tl = document.getElementById('str').value;
    var x = tl.split('|');
    var fnd = document.getElementById('dataPoint').value;
    var y = fnd.split(';');
    var stripe = document.getElementById('stripe').value;
    var z = stripe.split(',');
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        var data = eval(y[i]);
        var name = x[i];
        var strip = z[i];
        
        seriesOptions3[seriesCounter3] = 
        {
            name : name,
            dashStyle : strip,
            data : data
        };
        seriesCounter3++;
    }
    Highcharts.stockChart('cumChartResp',{
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 5
        },
        
        
    
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '14px'
            },
            symbolWidth: 42
        },
    
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
            text: 'Powered by Novagni',
            href: 'http://www.novagni.com.my'
        },
    
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Cumulative Returns (%)'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },
        plotOptions:{
            series:{
                dataGrouping:{
                    enabled: false
                },
                compare: 'percent',
                compareStart: true,
                lineWidth: 3
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: {point.change}%<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true,
            xDateFormat: '%A, %b %d, %Y'
        },
        //<b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/> '%d-%m-%Y' 

        title: {
            text: 'Cumulative Returns',
            style: {
                color: '#333333',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '18px'
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'The Start Date for all cumulative returns calculation for the periods of 1m, 3m, 6m & 1y is based in reference to the latest Start Date amongst the selected funds',
            style: {
                color: '#333333',
                fontSize: '14px'
            }
        },
        colors: ['#0067B1', 'black', '#865439', '#00FF00', '#FFD700'],
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        series: seriesOptions3
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs because the `rangeSelector` gets extremes from the navigator. You can set for each series `showInNavigator: true` to avoid that behaviour.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/njpe98hx/